# Pandas selecting columns meeting criteria A or B

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to search an answer to this bus couldnt find any.

I'm trying to select a subset of my dataframe that meet criteria 'A and (B or C)' so far I couldn't get it to work.

the code i'm trying:

```
df_subset = df[(df['a'] == A) & ((df['b']== B) or (df['b'].isnull()))]
```

this line is giving me the following error message

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().enter code here
```

is there anyway to make this to work? i know i can subset ('a'=A and 'b'=B) and ('a'=A and 'b'.isnull()) and merge the 2 subsets. but doing it in one line would be better.

Thanks

Comment: use `|` not `or`: `df_subset = df[(df['a'] == A) & ((df['b']== B) | (df['b'].isnull()))]`, you need to use the operators `&`, `|`, `~` for `and`, `or` and `not` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(list('ABC'), size=(20, 3)),
    columns=list('abc'))
df = df.mask(np.random.choice((True, False), size=(20, 3), p=(.1, .9)))

df

      a    b    c
0     A    C    C
1     C    C    B
2     B    C    A
3     C    A    C
4     A    A    C
5     A    C  NaN
6   NaN    B    A
7   NaN    B    C
8     A    A    A
9     A    B    C
10    B    A    B
11    B  NaN    A
12    A    C    A
13    C    C    C
14  NaN    C    C
15    B    C    A
16    C    B    A
17    A  NaN    B
18    C  NaN    A
19    A    C    B
```

***method 1***
[`pd.DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
df.query('a == "A" & (b == "B" | b != b)')
```

***method 2***
use series boolean operators

```
df[df.a.eq('A') & (df.b.eq('B') | df.b.isnull())]
```

***method 3***
correcting what you had

```
df[(df['a'] == 'A') & ((df['b'] == 'B') | df['b'].isnull())]
#                                       ^          
#                                       |

    a    b  c
9   A    B  C
17  A  NaN  B
```

Comment: thanks you! method 3 was what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Sinanju glad I could help.  ***method 2*** is identical to ***method 3***.  It just reflects my stylistic preference.  ***method 1*** is different, but I like to provide perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `|` for `or`, just like you used `&` for `and`.

This also means you need to be sure to parenthesize the two conditions, but you're already doing that.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue